# Markdown Syntax Broken in Atom.io

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

Markdown sytax won't render in [Atom.io](https://atom.io/).

Here are screenshots of other sytax highlighting that work perfectly (and Markdown's, which does not).

#### Python

[image: python_works]

#### JavaScript

[image]

However, Markdown syntax doesn't appear to be working at all?

[image]

### What I've Tried

I'm currently on the most stable version of Atom.io:

```
benjamingross@myhost:~$ atom --version
Atom    : 1.12.7
Electron: 1.3.13
Chrome  : 52.0.2743.82
Node    : 6.5.0
```

1. I've tried both the [`language-markdown`](https://atom.io/packages/language-markdown) and [`language-gfm`](https://github.com/atom/language-gfm) packages. I even uninstalled the `language-gfm` package.
2. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Atom.io
3. Found [this post](https://discuss.atom.io/t/syntax-highlight-on-markdown-preview-not-working/10062), [this post](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9075)
4. I have changed to each and every UI theme and Syntax theme that comes stock with Atom.io (where every other language continues to work, but `.md`  files or `.markdown` files do not)

I look at other webpages like the ones below, and it seems like other people have quite attractive markdown syntax highlighting out of the box with Atom.

> From the [markdown-preview](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview) webpage
>   [image]

Any idea on how to get the same beautiful markdown syntax highlighting as above?

BTW, my markdown-preview works fine...

### Update

Here are the results of my `~/.atom/config.cson`

```
benjamingross@myhost:~$ cat ~/.atom/config.cson 
"*":
  "bracket-matcher":
    autocompleteBrackets: false
    autocompleteSmartQuotes: false
  core:
    openEmptyEditorOnStart: false
    telemetryConsent: "limited"
    themes: [
      "atom-dark-ui"
      "atom-dark-syntax"
    ]
  editor:
    fontFamily: "monaco"
    fontSize: 16
    invisibles: {}
    softWrap: true
    tabLength: 4
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "8f9a4104-acbd-9a9c-c4fa-51fefd430c1d"
  "markdown-preview":
    useGitHubStyle: true
  metrics:
    userId: "5b177b4431829ba54f99ac607c1f52478649eff8"
  "one-dark-ui": {}
  "release-notes":
    viewedVersion: "0.95.0"
  "spell-check": {}
  "tree-view":
    hideIgnoredNames: true
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false
".md.text":
  editor:
    tabLength: 4
```

[image]

Comment: anything funny in your `~/.atom/config.cson` maybe ?

Comment: @birdspider, I just added the output of my `~/.atom/config.cson`

Comment: well one thing I would try is to backup/move the config.cson and restart atom

Comment: @birdspider, that did it! Great solve that I'm obviously kicking myself for not trying! If you want to put a two line blurb about doing it that way as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the specific issue and under the assumtion that re/uninstalling didn't help - one culprit could be a user configuration possibly under `~/.atom/` i.e the main config file `~/.atom/config.cson`.

Those files usually survive a reinstall on *nix systems.

Try backing it up or moving it and re-starting the `atom` editor so it generates a new one.